# Extra spaces in the timeline page

Tags: discussion, design, timeline

There is some extra spaces in the question's timeline page. For example this [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/3122/timeline)'s timeline page I'm seeing extra space for the timeline sections.

Is the spaces for any placeholder? or any other purpose?

If not, it should be a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Screenshot for reference:

[image: Extra Spaces in the timeline page]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the issue is resolved now.

The recent timeline page is below:

[image: Alignment issue fixed in Timeline]